# ¿Es correcto el uso de la preposición «de» en este caso?

Tags: gramática, preposiciones, complemento-directo

Estoy redactando un texto y me surge la inquietud de si debo o no emplear la palabra **de**.

El caso es el siguiente:

> La solución es en muchas ocasiones imposible realizarla de forma analítica

o

> La solución es en muchas ocasiones imposible **de** realizarla de forma analítica.

¿Cuál de las dos opciones es la correcta?

Comment: Usar simplemente la preposición _de_ no constituye un dequeísmo, que [se define](https://dle.rae.es/?id=CGdEzSW) como "el uso, normalmente censurado, de la secuencia _de que_ para introducir una oración subordinada que no admite ese régimen verbal". Ejemplo: "le dije de que viniera" en vez de "le dije que viniera".

Answer (score 3):

Los adjetivos que denotan posibilidad, facilidad o dificultad, como *imposible*, *fácil*, *difícil*, admiten complementos preposicionales formados por la preposición *de* y un infinitivo transitivo **sin complemento directo**. Por tanto, las dos opciones de las que dispones para escribir la frase serían:

> La solución es en muchas ocasiones imposible realizarla de forma analítica.
>   La solución es en muchas ocasiones imposible de realizar de forma analítica.

La variante *imposible de realizarla* se puede observar en la lengua oral, pero es incorrecta en la lengua estándar dado que se está usando un complemento preposicional con un verbo transitivo y su complemento directo ("la"), denominado en este caso *reasuntivo de apoyo*. Basta con eliminarlo para que la frase sea correcta (o bien eliminar la preposición).

Comment: La versión con sin de (con *la*) me parece bien escrita también, aunque con una interpretación diferente: *Realizarla de forma analítica es, en muchas ocasiones, imposible*, con *la solución* siendo un objeto tematizado (y por tanto la coaparición del pronombre *la*). No creo que sea el intento, pero vamos, válido sería.

Comment: Perdón, podría ser más claro? no comprendo la respuesta. Gracias.

Comment: @michaelherediaperez resumiendo: de las dos opciones que planteaste en la pregunta, solo la primera es válida (la que no usa el _de_). La segunda (la que sí usa el _de_) podría ser válida si en vez de _realizarla_ escribes _realizar_.